# Gradle Build fails only in Tests (Android Studio, Kotlin)

Tags: android, gradle, junit, kotlin

I am having an Android Multi-Module Project, and wanted to add JUnit Tests. Interestingly after adding the first Testclass, the Gradle Build failed when i wanted to start the test. The error Messages were unclear to me, as they would not make any sense.

The Gradle Module depends on a Base-Module with default dependencies.

### build.gradle: core-libs

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    api "org.koin:koin-android:1.0.2"
    api "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.1"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.11"
}
```

### build.gradle: core-test-libs

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    testApi "org.koin:koin-test:1.0.2"
    testApi "org.amshove.kluent:kluent-android:1.42"
    testApi "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

### build.gradle: main-module

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.0"
    implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.11"

    api project(":core-libs")
    testApi project(":core-test-libs")
}
```

### The Test Class

```
class RegionListJsoupParserTest : KoinTest {

    private val underTest = RegionListJsoupParser()

    @Test
    fun parseRegionResult() {
        val testFile = File("Ligen - Turnier.de.html")
        val testDocument = Jsoup.parse(testFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())

        val result = underTest.parse(testDocument)

        println(result)
    }
}
```

Simply Building the Project via Android Studio works perfectly fine. But when I want to run the testmethod, the compileKotlin fails with a bunch of errors:

```
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\QueryDateTimeFormatter.kt: (4, 12): Unresolved reference: threeten
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\QueryDateTimeFormatter.kt: (5, 12): Unresolved reference: threeten
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\QueryDateTimeFormatter.kt: (7, 10): Class 'QueryDateTimeFormatter' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun format(dateTime: LocalDateTime): String defined in de.tim_brueggenthies.android.baselibraries.LocalDateTimeFormatter
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\QueryDateTimeFormatter.kt: (9, 28): Unresolved reference: DateTimeFormatter
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\QueryDateTimeFormatter.kt: (9, 48): Unresolved reference: DateTimeFormatter
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\QueryDateTimeFormatter.kt: (11, 5): 'format' overrides nothing
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\QueryDateTimeFormatter.kt: (11, 35): Unresolved reference: LocalDateTime
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClient.kt: (4, 12): Unresolved reference: threeten
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClient.kt: (8, 74): Unresolved reference: LocalDateTime
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClient.kt: (8, 117): Unresolved reference: LocalDateTime
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClient.kt: (20, 31): Unresolved reference: LocalDateTime
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClient.kt: (20, 47): Unresolved reference: LocalDateTime
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClient.kt: (22, 30): Unresolved reference: LocalDateTime
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClient.kt: (22, 46): Unresolved reference: LocalDateTime
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClientImpl.kt: (5, 12): Unresolved reference: threeten
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClientImpl.kt: (17, 74): Unresolved reference: LocalDateTime
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClientImpl.kt: (17, 98): Unresolved reference: LocalDateTime
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\TurnierClientImpl.kt: (40, 17): Unresolved reference: LocalDateTime
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (5, 12): Unresolved reference: koin
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (7, 33): Unresolved reference: module
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (8, 5): Unresolved reference: single
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (8, 32): Unresolved reference: get
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (8, 39): Unresolved reference: get
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (8, 46): Unresolved reference: get
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (9, 5): Unresolved reference: single
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (10, 5): Unresolved reference: single
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (10, 37): Unresolved reference: get
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (10, 44): Unresolved reference: get
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (11, 5): Unresolved reference: single
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (12, 5): Unresolved reference: single
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\KoinModules.kt: (13, 5): Unresolved reference: factory
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\TurnierApiDi.kt: (3, 12): Unresolved reference: koin
e: E:\Remote Repos\tura-badminton-android-app\turnierapiclient\src\main\java\de\tim_brueggenthies\android\turnierapiclient\di\TurnierApiDi.kt: (8, 9): Unresolved reference: loadKoinModules
```

All "unresolved references" are not valid, and the not overriden methods are overriden as well.

Would be nice if someone has an idea why this Problem occurs.

Comment: Show us your gradle dependencies. You're probably missing some testImplementaion or androidTestImplementation

Comment: I edited my question to include the gradle dependencies. I would appreciate if you could check it!

Comment: You have no imports for the test class and you have no dependencies in your `testImplementation` Gradle configuration.

Comment: Well the dependencies like junit are declared via testApi, so they are accessible for other modules depending on the main-module.
What do you mean by no imports for the test class?

Comment: Did you find resolution for this?